# Intent for Browser-Request

Tags: android, android-intent

We want to create an intent-filter for capturing browser-requests. Is it possible to catch something like this by an e.g. intent-service or a broadcastreceiver? 
Which category etc should an intent-fiter for the service have? We have found a piece of code, but it didn't work:

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 <data android:scheme="http" />
```

Maybe somebody can help us with this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding following lines to AndroidManifest.xml file will make BrowserActivity to receive intents for capturing browser requests:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <activity android:name=".BrowserActivitiy"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <data android:scheme="http"/> 
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/02/21/android-intents/) is a link that describes in detail.

Don't forget to add internet access permission to your manifest.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```